# How do I transform a vector into a new vector using range-v3?

Tags: c++, vector, range-v3

I am coming from the C# world where I can write something like:

```cs
var newList = oldList.Select(x => x * 2).Where(x => x > 3).ToList();
```

This allows me to take a list, transform it in some way, and store the result in a new list.

I would like to do the same in C++ using [range-v3](/questions/tagged/range-v3). I understand how the transformations work, but does [range-v3](/questions/tagged/range-v3) provide similar "sink" methods for computing and collecting the results?

I am looking for something like `toVector`, which would compute a resulting range into a freshly allocated `std::vector`.

Comment: You can build a `std::vector` from a `range`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you give an example? An equivalent to my C# snippet above would be perfect.

Comment: Using the standard library you could do `std::for_each(oldList.begin(), oldList.end(), [&newList](auto& val) {if(val > 3) newList.push_back(val * 2); });` But you would have to create the `newList` variable before calling it. [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4eace3968a9d84b0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do:

```
std::vector<int> v2 = v
                    | ranges::view::transform([](int x) { return x * 2; })
                    | ranges::view::filter([](int x) { return x > 3; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f0adb8785569901)

Or, if you prefer `auto` on the left:

```
auto v2 = v 
        | ranges::view::transform([](int x) { return x * 2; }) 
        | ranges::view::filter([](int x) { return x > 3; }) 
        | ranges::to_vector;
```

Comment: Can you add a version using `auto v2 = ` on the left? I'm interested in how the API works.

Comment: @sdgfsdh: `auto` would give some range (lazy) view. Not sure what you expect.

Comment: Yes, but is there some modifier that can be added to the RHS that makes `auto v2` into an `std::vector`? e.g. `... | ranges::toVector();`

Comment: @sdgfsdh Close. It's `| ranges::to_vector` (or `| ranges::to_<std::list>()`).